# Magento 2 : How to display cms_page custom attribute image in frontend?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, frontend, image

After save image is store in pub/media/cms/page/attribute/my_image.

And save image name in database cms_page table my custom column.
So how to display image in frontend ?

**Backend image**

[image: Cms page custom attribute]

Fronted Image :-

[image: Fronted Home Page]

Comment: Whic product attribute image you want to show on front end? And where need to show? Please add more details in question. Or add some screen shots.

Comment: I have changed my question so please see

Comment: But on home page where you want to show that image?

Comment: After category menu

Comment: Please check answer and if it is useful then please do upvote. Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Hello ZealousWeb, Your code is not work so I did debug and find issue.
Issue :- our switch condition is not gone.
So how we can solve this ?

Comment: Please check updated answer without switch case.

Comment: Hello ZealousWeb, our condition is not gone. please update the code ?

Comment: Hi, i have updated code.

Comment: Hello ZealousWeb, plz changes your code.
change block file function :- public function getPageImage()
    {
        $fullAction = $this->_request->getFullActionName();
        if($fullAction == 'cms_page_view' || $fullAction == 'cms_index_index') {
            $imageHtml = $this->getCmsPage();
            return $imageHtml;
        }
    }
Add function in block file :- 
public function getImageCheck()
    {
        $pageLoad = $this->pageFactory->create()->load($this->cmsPage->getId());
        $bannerImage = $pageLoad->getCmsImageAttribute();
        return $bannerImage;
    }

Comment: Hello ZealousWeb, plz changes your code. 
change block file function :- layout file : Remove before = '-' , 
<?php $bannerImage = $block->getImageCheck(); ?>
<?php $pageImage = $block->getPageImage(); ?>
<?php if($bannerImage): ?>
    <div class="sec-outer">
        <img src="<?php echo $pageImage;?>" class="banner-image">
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Plz update code. after I do accept answer. Thanks!

Comment: And plz share your skype id

Comment: Updated code. Please accept now.

Comment: For what you need?

Comment: Check this [module](https://github.com/theshreyas/magento-2-quickies/tree/main/CmsImage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow all the steps to show image in cms pages. Here i have taken custom collumn name "banner" which is created in "cms_page" table. Please change your code according to your column name.

> Step 1:- Please create one block file named Image.php under path
> PackageName/Banner/Block/Banner/

**Below code is for get image from custom column.**

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\Banner\Block\Banner;

class Image extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_request;

    protected $_cmsPage;

    protected $_pageFactory;

    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $cmsPage,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_cmsPage = $cmsPage;
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getMediaUrl()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    }

    public function getCmsPage()
    {
        $media_url = $this->getMediaUrl();
        $pageLoad = $this->_pageFactory->create()->load($this->_cmsPage->getId());
        $bannerImage = $media_url.'cms/page/attribute/'.$pageLoad->getBanner();
        return $bannerImage;
    }

    public function getPageImage() 
    { 
        $fullAction = $this->_request->getFullActionName(); 
        if($fullAction == 'cms_page_view' || $fullAction == 'cms_index_index') { 
            $imageHtml = $this->getCmsPage(); 
            return $imageHtml; 
        } 
    }

    public function getImageCheck() 
    { 
        $pageLoad = $this->pageFactory->create()->load($this->cmsPage->getId()); 
        $bannerImage = $pageLoad->getCmsImageAttribute(); 
        return $bannerImage; 
    }
}
```

> Step 2:- Create image.phtml file under path
> PackageName/Banner/view/frontend/templates/

```
<?php $bannerImage = $block->getImageCheck(); ?> 
<?php $pageImage = $block->getPageImage(); ?> 
<?php if($bannerImage): ?> 
    <div class="sec-outer"> <img src="<?php echo $pageImage;?>" class="banner-image"> </div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

> Step 3:- Now create file default.xml file under path
> PackageName/Banner/view/frontend/layout/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="PackageName\Banner\Block\Banner\Image" name="header.banner" template="PackageName_Banner::image.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

With the use of above code, image will be shown in page top means after category menu.

Please check and let me know.